# Angular.js how to programatically create new ng-model

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm currently trying to add `"<label>Foos name</label><input ng-model="Foo"/>"` programmatically into the dom as part of a string, What i currently have is this.

```
.directive( 'showData', function ( $compile ) {
 return {
scope: true,
link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
  var el;

  attrs.$observe( 'template', function ( tpl ) {
    if ( angular.isDefined( tpl ) ) {
      // compile the provided template against the current scope
      el = $compile(tpl)( scope );

      // stupid way of emptying the element
      element.html("");

      // add the template content
      element.append( el );
    }
  });
}
 };
  });
```

Problem is, `$scope.Foo` doesn't exist...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a typo i see `<input ng-model="Foo"/>"` not `ng-modal`

Comment: Thanks for that, it is spelt correctly in the app. Just doesn't work..

Comment: Where are yoi checking the value of `Foo`. I see that `scope:true` so changes would not reflect in parent scope. Remove `scope:true` and try.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out why it wasn't working.. Something really simple too..

I had $scope.foo = '' defined in my controller which was overriding the one included in the string.